# Adjust Prev and Next button to the corners of Table

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables

I have a datatable that has a `Previous` and `Next` button at the top and bottom of the table.

My question is how can I adjust the `Previous` button at the corner left and the `Next` button at the corner right regardless of the table width for now this is my `sDom`

`"sDom": '<"top"ifp<"clear">>rt<"bottom"p>',`

tysm

Comment: I don't think it will possible to give you any direction without seeing the HTML and CSS you are working with.

Comment: for now the only code i can give to you is the code under datables no more added any code coz i dont know where to start, very srry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to create a custom buttons for Prev and Next; then append it to the `dom` of your DataTables:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  pagingType: "simple",
  sDom: '<"top"if<"#top"><"clear">>rt<"#bottom">'
});

var cust_btn = '<div class="row custom_btn"><div class="col-xs-6 text-left"><div><button type="button" class="btn btn-default prev">Prev</button></div></div><div class="col-xs-6 text-right">   <div><button type="button" class="btn btn-default next">Next</button> </div></div></div>'
$('#bottom').append(cust_btn);
$('#top').append(cust_btn);


$('.next').on('click', function() {
  table.page('next').draw('page');
});

$('.prev').on('click', function() {
  table.page('previous').draw('page');
});
```

Attach a click event on the buttons then use the page API of the DataTables.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mattmorz/9ru1gLez/2/) for reference.

Comment: actually thats what i did. i create custom controls and it worked well without thinking on how to move the custome `prev` and `next` anyways thnx